# Memory management differences in return by value

Tags: c++, oop, reference

I'm trying to follow a tutorial [here:](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/classes2/) regarding overloading operators, and I've found something that's really confused me.

There was a previous question on this very website [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6556413/859249) where this tutorial was discussed, namely regarding how the variables in the class were preserved because the whole class was passed back by value.

Whilst experimenting with the class definition I toyed with making the integer variables pointers (perhaps not sensible - but just to experiment!) as follows:

```
class CVector {  

  int* x;
  int* y;

  public:

  CVector () {};
  CVector (int,int);
  CVector operator + (CVector);
  ~CVector ();
};
```

In the class constructor I allocate memory for the two integers, and in the class deconstructor I delete the allocated memory.

I also tweak the overloaded operator function as follows:

```
CVector CVector::operator+ (CVector param) {
  CVector temp;
  *temp.x = *x + *param.x;
  *temp.y = *y + *param.y;
  return (temp);   
}
```

For the original code, where the class has simple integer variables the return by value of the entire class completes successfully.

However, after I change the variables to int pointers, the return by value of the class does **not** complete successfully as the integer variables are no longer intact.

I assume the deconstructor is being called when the temporary CVector goes out of scope and deletes these member integer pointers, but the class itself is still returned by value.

I'd like to be able to return by value the CVector with the memory allocated to its member variables intact, whilst ensuring the temporary CVector is correctly deleted when it goes out of scope.

Is there any way this can be done?

Many thanks!

Comment: What are you trying to do with those pointers?

Comment: Nothing special, I've just replaced normal ints with them as an experiment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are not following the [rule of the three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29), which basically boils down to: *if you manage resources, then you should provide *copy constructor*, *assignment operator* and *destructor* for your class*.

Assuming that on construction you are allocating memory for the pointers, the problem is that the implicit copy constructor is *shallow*, and will copy the pointers, but you probably want a *deep* copy. In the few cases where you do not want a *deep* copy, control of the manage *shared* resource becomes more complicated, and I would use a `shared_ptr` rather than trying to do it manually.

Answer (score 2):

You need to provide a copy constructor for `CVector` to make copies of the allocated memory. Otherwise, when you return by value, the pointer values will simply be copied and then the `temp` object is destructed, deallocating the ints. The returned copy now points to invalid memory.

```
CVector( const CVector& other )
: x ( new int(other.x) )
, y ( new int(other.y) )
{}
```

Note that it is bad idea to be using raw pointers in your class, especially more than one. If the allocation of `y` fails above and `new` throws you've got a memory leak (because `x` is left dangling). You could've allocated within the constructor itself, instead of the initializer list, either within a `try`-`catch`, or using the `std::nothrow` version of `new`, then check for `nullptr`. But it makes the code very verbose and error prone.

The best solution is to use some smart pointer class such as `std::unique_ptr` to hold pointers. If you were to use `std::shared_ptr` to hold those pointers, you can even share the ints between copies of the class.

Comment: Thanks.

On your comment regarding raw pointers - I didn't realise it was possible to declare variables in a constructor?

Comment: You're not declaring them in the constructor, you're allocating memory and assigning this memory to pointers declared in the class definition.

Comment: Also look at @David Rodríguez's answer, you should provide an assignment operator as well for CVector.

Answer (score 1):

The return-by-value causes the returned, `temp` object to be *copied* to another object, a temporary "return object". After `temp` is copied, it is destructed, deallocating your ints. The easiest way to handle this is to use a reference-counted pointer such as `tr1::shared_ptr<>`. It will keep the memory allocated until the last reference to it is dropped, then it will deallocate.

Answer (score 0):

There are few problems in the given code.

(1) You should allocate proper memory to `*x` and `*y` inside the constructor; otherwise accessing them is undefined behavior.

```
CVector () : x(new int), y(new int) {}
```

Also make sure that to have copy constructor and `operator =` where you `delete x` and `delete y` before reallocating them; otherwise it will lead to hazards.

(2) `delete` them in destructor

```
~CVector () { delete x; delete y; }
```

(3) Pass argument to `operator +` by `const` reference to avoid unnecessary copying.

```
CVector CVector::operator+ (const CVector &param)
{
  // code
}
```

Since you are learning with playing around with pointers, I will not comment on the design perspective of your `class`, like if they should be pointer or variables or containers and so on.